# ELAN1000 and FreeBSD11-RELEASE

Tags: drivers, freebsd, touchpad, input, xinput

I want to use FreeBSD as Desktop on my ASUS laptop, but I can't use its touchpad... I try multiple things with synaptics driver, use xf86-input-synaptics from ports (when I use the pkg one, the wifi chipset seems to be unable to scan networks after reboot...)

I try multiple configurations, but I think the first problem is there is no /dev/psm0 so Xorg isn't able to use it...

I know my touchpad is an ELAN1000.

I'm not sure what I should try now... (switch to -STABLE branch?)

Comment: You'd better ask on `freebsd-x11@freebsd.org` mail list.

Answer (score 0):

On my ThinkPad X220 the trackpad does not start to work unless I enable it in `/boot/loader.conf`:

```
hw.psm.synaptics_support="1"
```

In `/etc/rc.conf` I already had:

```
moused_enable="YES"
```

With this the touchpad worked in the console. It was furthermore auto-detected by X with no modifications. This route seems to make the touchpad emulate a mouse. This is more than enough for me as I prefer the trackpoint.

Further info on Synaptics in the [Wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/SynapticsTouchpad#How_to_use_it).

Much old info is floating around but X is really good at auto-detecting things today. Rather than using `xorg.conf` I would recommend that you start using `/usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and only make entries for items not autodetected. See the [Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x-config.html)

If you want to go the X driver route - have a look at the forum post [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/54872/). He explicitly states that this will not work with `moused` enabled. Also note that he says you should use it from ports - not pkg. In other words - you should build it locally against your own tree. Things might have been fixed since.

Comment: I already tried this too, but this doesn't works for me, with this, the pointer was displayed in the console, but the touchpad didn't work.

This works with synaptics and some Elan touchpad, but mine seems more recent and not supported already...

Anyway, maybe I will keep trying later, but for now I will try to use OpenBSD instead (seems to be less strict with laptops hardware)